# You can't go out dressed like that vs You can't go out dressing like that

Tags: grammar

Are both sentences correct? One with "dressed" and the other with "dressing". If they do, please explain the different meaning between 2 sentences.

Comment: *You can't go out **dressed** like that* OR *You can't go out **looking** like that* are the two idiomatic usages. Same as *He went to work dressed casually, She went to work looking smart*. Where *He went to work **dressing** casually* might be syntactically valid, but no-one would ever say it. And *She went to work **looked** smart* is syntactically invalid.

Comment: Learners often have a hard time with gerund-nouns...

Answer (score 3):

The past/passive participle "dressed" (or the adjective derived from it) has the sense of "having dressed like that" (the act of dressing is complete) or "being dressed like that"

The present participle "dressing" would mean "currently dressing"

So "... dressed like that" means "in those clothes", and is a normal thing to say (but rather patronising).

But "You can't go out dressing like that" means "You can't go out while putting on clothes like that." It would not be a normal thing to say (and so I'd probably assume it was a mistake)

Comment: dressing can be a noun here rather than a present participle...

Answer (score 0):

You can't go out **dressing** like that [and live in my house]. [a general statement]

My **dressing** is always a subject for debate in my family.
**Dressing** like that is not great.

**

> dressing is not a verb those sentences; it's a gerund noun.

**

VERSUS

You can't go out **dressed** like that.
The verb form is: to be dressed in jeans, in formal clothes. etc. to be dressed= to wear certain clothes

That is a verb.

Comment: In my youth it's what every father said to their teenage daughters at least once.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I really do not understand that comment since I do not know to which it refers.

Comment: You can't go out dressed like that!